# Android SDK manager doesn't open

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have installed SDK and eclipse, but SDK manager and avd manager doesn't open, a black screen flashes for a Milli seconds  and closes. Here is what I have tried :-
( NB - I am using a 32-bit Windows 8 that runs on x86 processor )
Tried to define environment variables to a path -

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
JAVA_JRE  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

But still, it doesn't work.
On trying to run android.bat, I get a window that says..

```
ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java installed on your system. We
recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html
```

Replaced JRE 1.7 with JRE 1.6. It also didn't help

Comment: Have you installed JDK?

Comment: Yes I have installed JDK and JRE

Comment: @AleksandrM should I be using an x86 version or x64 version of JDK and JRE? Please make that clear.

Comment: If you are running on "32 bit windows" then x86.

Comment: Yes that is what I have done, I can make apps,create projects etc,but not run the sdk. Should I define a JAVA_JRE too?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have installed JRE/JDK, then add JRE/JDK to Environment variables > PATH:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

Or

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin
```

Please note that the actual JDK version installed on your machine may differ.

Comment: what names should I use ?
JAVA_HOME and JAVA_JRE?

Comment: Can you illustrate? I mean I dont want to mess up the thing

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is also fine, just make sure to include `...\bin`, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`

Comment: Defined new system variables as given below:-
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
JAVA_JRE  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
And rebooted the machine,still android SDK manager doesn't open.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH system, and check if you have a java.exe file in C:\Windows\system32; remove it (make a backup) and try to reinstall your android sdk. I think you have another virtual java machine running in your pc.

For check your current java machine: **open a console and type "java -version"**

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to try the new Android Studio (released under the 2013 Google I/O) it's most suitable that start from scratch about configuring environment.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: Have you used it? Is it just like eclipse? I am asking this because I have time limitations for this project and cant really spend time learning an IDE at this point of time. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry be late here for response. And, yes of course! things like designer, ddms, debugger, avd manager are really the same interface. Just try it by yourself.